# Jquery animate height or width causing floating elements to jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a bunch of boxes floated left inside a container. They are perfectly sized to fit like blocks inside a space. 2 columns sized 50% each.

```
<div style="padding:10px; overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:50%;">block1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:50%;">block2</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:50%;">block3</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:50%;">block4</div>
</div>
```

I then have a jquery based script to animate the removal of a box as follows

```
function remove(element){
  element.animate({width:0,height:0},2000,function(){
    element.remove()
})}
```

My issue occurs right at the point where the animation starts. I believe it is the animation creating an initial width and/or height value that is just slightly larger than what it actually is. Sometimes the height and width in px value is a decimal but animation rounds it up in the initialization.

For example, I tested it with an animation time over 200000 and it clearly reveal that the animation process rounded up decimal px values such as 154.8px -> 155px and started the animation at 155px instead of 154.8px. This is causing a quick jumping in down or side to side on my floating elements depending on if the width and/or height has a decimal value.

My block in px values is 252px width and 154.8px height but when animation starts:[image]

How can I fix this problem without changing the 50% width of my boxes. Does animation feature contain any settings to round down start?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by removing 1px from starting height and width like so

```
function remove(element){
  startHeight=element.height()-1+"px"
  startWidth=element.width()-1+"px"
  element.css({width:startWidth,height:startHeight}).animate({width:0,height:0},200,function(){
    element.remove()
})}
```